# How do I fix the "No resource found that matches the given name" error?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, error-handling, compiler-errors

I transferred an android studio project from one PC to another and as I imported my project in to the new PC, I got this error:"No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background'). "

Here's the code the error is stemming from:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18"
                android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I'm sorry if this question seems to be lacking in detail, but the information I've provided is all I really know about this issue. My apologies.

Comment: Do you have your resource image in `Drawable`? If yes, check that you wrote correct image extension in xml.

Comment: i think this image come from google play service library. try by adding google play service

Comment: I added the google play services sdk but I'm still getting the same error. Also, how would I check if I wrote the correct image extension in xml?